# jqplot Line chart not working properly in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jqplot

I have Line chart plotted using jqplot. In chrome it is working properly as expected.
[image]

But in IE it is not working properly.

[image: IE]

Here is my code for drawing the chart.

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot(dev, data, {
            animate: true,
            animateReplot: true,
            axes:{
                xaxis:{
                    renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                    tickOptions:{
                        formatString:'%b',
                        angle: -90
                            },
                    tickInterval:'1 month'
                },
                yaxis:{
                      label:title,
                      labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                      tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                      tickOptions: {
                          angle: 15
                      },

                    }
            },
            legend:{ 
                show:true,
                    renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
                    location: 's' ,
                    placement : "outside",
                    marginTop : "35px",
                    border:'none',
                    labels : ['value', 'value', 'value'],
                    rendererOptions: {
                        numberRows: 1
                    }
                 },
                highlighter: { 
                    show: true,
                    showTooltip: true

                },
            series:[{lineWidth:4, markerOptions:{style:'square'}}]
            });
```

Please can somebody tell me how this will make working on IE.And I added this to script and it also not useful.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../../javascript/jqplot/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

Your ideas are welcome. Thank you.

**EDIT**
This is data array

var data = [[],[],[]];

```
        for(i=0;i<ret.length;i++){

            for (var key in ret[i]) {

            data[i].push([ key, parseInt(ret[i][key]) ]);


            }
        }
```

ret is a JSON object returned from a AJAX call.

Comment: What version of IE you are using?  
What is the order of the script when you load them on the page? 
How are you creating the `data` array?

Comment: @Gyandeep Thanks for the reply and I mentioned above what the data array is. And the version of the IE is 10.What are you mean by order?

Comment: Do you see any errors or warnings in the IE debug console?

Comment: please provide an example data array. give us the same array you had for the above graph in the pic

Comment: @Gyandeep [[[1,497],[2,437],[3,511],[4,507],....],[[1,361],[2,303],...],[[1,250],[2,400],....]] like wise. I think no problem with data set because it is working with chrome perfectly.

Comment: @Marc No there is no errors or warnings.

Comment: According to your data, its not working [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/FCvmL/2/)  
You are usingg `dataaxisrenderer` and u r supplying 1, 2,3... as your data. it should be dates

Comment: @Gyandeep thank you for the point. Can you please tell me how can I overcome this problem? How can I use months instead of numbers?